# how to load shell environment variables when Emacs starts py-shell?

Tags: python, bash, shell, emacs, ipython

I'm working for a university and they have their own libraries and paths for python libraries. Every time I start `ipython`, I need to run a shell script (e.g. `/etc/university/env.sh`)

The problem is that emacs doesn't recognize the env.sh file. When I do py-shell, emacs always envokes Python WITHOUT any pre-set environment variables.

Is there a way to make emacs run `/etc/corporate/env.sh` before starting python?

Answer (score 1):

In `/home/ccfenix/mypython.sh` (make sure `chmod +x`, Emacs does this on auto):

```
#!/bin/bash

# . /etc/corporate/env.sh
export SOMEVAR=10
python "$@"
```

In `~/.emacs`:

```lisp
(defun my-python ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/home/ccfenix/mypython.sh"))
```

And to test: <kbd>M-x mypython</kbd>:

```
import os
print os.environ["SOMEVAR"]
# => 10
```

Comment: thanks abo-abo! however, how can Ipython pickup my-python? i suppose without specific instruction, ipython.el will pickup /usr/bin/ipython ?

Comment: Just replace python with ipython in ~/mypython.sh

Comment: Thanks providing this. However, it should be possible in a more natural way: https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1288239

Answer (score 0):

After running your /etc/university/env.sh, start Emacs from this shell.
Then the variables set before are known.